# Couchbase Document Revision Conflict with missing document

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I was told by my team that a document that other documents are referencing is missing.  I have the document saved in a backup and I'm trying to add it to the database through the Sync Gateway using curl.

`curl -vXPUT -H'Content-Type:application/json' -d"@mydocument" "http://128.0.0.1:4985/mydatabase/aa987654-3210-4567-89cc-cba121212121"`

I am getting the following response:

`{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document revision conflict"}`

However, if I try to get the document using that id:

`curl -vXGET "http://128.0.0.1:4985/mydatabase/aa987654-3210-4567-89cc-cba121212121"`

I get the response:

`{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}`

I've also tried;

`curl -vXGET "http://128.0.0.1:4985/mydatabase/aa987654-3210-4567-89cc-cba121212121?revs=true&open_revs=all"`

It comes back with the same response.

I also tried logging into the Couchbase server and querying the database directly:

`select * from mydatabase use keys "aa987654-3210-4567-89cc-cba121212121"`

It came back with a result size of 0.

```
  "results": [],
  "metrics": {
    "elapsedTime": "1.523366ms",
    "executionTime": "1.442059ms",
    "resultCount": 0,
    "resultSize": 0
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what to do as it says there is no document by that id, but if I try to add it, it says there's a conflict.  What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What versions of Couchbase Server, Sync Gateway, and Couchbase Lite are you using?

Comment: We are using 4.6.2 for the Couchbase Server.  
Sync Gateway is 1.4.1